# How could I disable all python shell interaction in emacs

Tags: python

How could I disable all python shell interaction in emacs on `python-mode`?

Such as:

```
C-c C-z       open a python shell
C-c C-c       run the content of the buffer in the opened python shell
C-c C-r       run the selected region in the python shell
C-c C-c       python-shell-send-buffer
C-c C-p       run-python
```

`python-shell-send-buffer` locks the emacs and I am unable to use it, hence I want to disalbe it.

I have set those keybindings to `nil` but still they are working.

```
(global-set-key (kbd "C-c C-p") 'nil)
(global-set-key (kbd "C-c C-c") 'nil)
```

Comment: [Related](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/53841/how-are-major-modes-and-local-keymaps-associated).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to undefine the bindings in the mode local map, not in the global map.

Something like this if you are using `python mode`:

```
(define-key python-mode-map (kbd "C-c C-p") 'undefined)
```

or if you use `elpy-mode` then try:

```
(define-key elpy-mode-map (kbd "C-c C-p") 'undefined)
```

and similarly for the other keys you want to undefine.

I always use `'undefined` in this situation, I don't know if nil should work as well.

Comment: I have tried it for `C-c C-c"` but still it works

Comment: maybe it is keybinding on elpy?

Comment: Yes, do “C-h k C-c C-c” to see what function is being called.